# easy switch case problem.... [objective c]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, switch-statement

if comment the nslog-line, there is an error:

> Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared
>   identifier 'alert'

```
switch ([[array objectAtIndex:0]intValue]) {
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"Allergie alarm");   << commenting this, gives me an error!!!
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"blabal"
                              message: @"balbalb"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to declare a new variable inside a `case` you need to open a new scope. To open a new scope simply use curly braces as others have already written.

Answer (score 4):

You are using multiline case statement. Your statements must be enclosed in `{` and `}`. Hence:

```
case 2: {
    NSLog(@"Allergie alarm");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"blabal"
                          message: @"balbalb"
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below

```
switch ([[array objectAtIndex:0]intValue]) {
    case 2:
       {
           NSLog(@"Allergie alarm");   << commenting this, gives me an error!!!
           UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"blabal"
                              message: @"balbalb"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
           [alert show];
           [alert release];
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

EDIT:
Use Curly brackets for the statement of `Case`.

Answer (score 1):

```
case 2:
{
    NSLog(@"Allergie alarm");   << commenting this, gives me an error!!!
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"blabal"
                          message: @"balbalb"
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    break;
}
```

Enclose the statements in `{}` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you should not declare variables inside switch

try this way

```
UIAlertView *alert;
switch ([[array objectAtIndex:0]intValue]) {
    case 2:

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"blabal"
                              message: @"balbalb"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

or enclose it in the braces

```
    case 2:
    {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"blabal"
                              message: @"balbalb"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set delegate of alert

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"blabal"
                              message: @"balbalb"
                              delegate: self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Regards,
Shyam

Answer (score 0):

```
////some code
switch ([[array objectAtIndex:0]intValue]) {
  case 2:
    NSLog(@"Allergie alarm");   << commenting this, gives me an error!!!
    [self showAlert];
    break;
default:
    break;
}
////some code




- (void) showAlert{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"blabal"
                          message: @"balbalb"
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
  }
```

Comment: Adding a method and thus another method call to work around this simple problem is not a good solution, although it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is not scope like thing. the problem is when he comment the nslog statement then compiler read the code some thing like that

case 2:UIAlertView *alert ....

means think this is a parameter of the case 2.
i check this the only first line after case two should not be a declaration line of variable so that means their is not scope problem

```
switch (2) {
     case 2:
         ;
        //NSLog(@"Allergie alarm");  // << commenting this, gives me an error!!!
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"blabal" message: @"balbalb" delegate: nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         [alert release];
         break;

     default:
         break;
 }
```